# Is there a free Eclipse plugin to tidy XML documents?

Tags: xml, eclipse

I have already looked at oXygen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Eclipse [Web Tools Platform](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/) includes an XML editor that can reformat XML documents. It isn't the best XML editor, nor is the formatting as configurable as some other tools, but it is free and easily installed since it is part of a top level Eclipse project, so you should give it a try and see if it meets your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can also format xml documents with Rinzo. It's free.
http://editorxml.sourceforge.net/index.html